# Discord Py AttributeError when trying to get the end of a url

Tags: python, discord.py

Below is my code for saving a users pfp how ever i got tired of it only saving as a png so i decided to add a check if the avatar URL ends with gif however it is simply throwing out the error "'Asset' object has no attribute 'endswith'" what am i doing wrong?

```
@bot.command()
@commands.check(Owner)
async def avs(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    member = ctx.author if not member else member
    if member.avatar_url.endswith('.gif'):
        await member.avatar_url_as(format="gif").save(fp=f"{member}.gif")
        await ctx.send(f"Saved pfp of {member}")
    else:
        await member.avatar_url_as(format="png").save(fp=f"{member}.png")
        await ctx.send(f"Saved pfp of {member}")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Member.avatar_url` returns a `discord.Asset` instance, you can cast it to a string to get the URL of the asset.

```py
if str(member.avatar_url).endswith('.gif'):
```

#### Reference:

- [`Member.avatar_url`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.avatar_url)
- [`discord.Asset`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Asset)

Comment: This gets rid of the error but running the cmd gives me a png despite currently having a gif pfp. Thank you for the help though! ill look into the references and see if i can find anything

Comment: Try printing the URL, maybe it doesn't end with `.gif`. Remember to accept the answer if it helped though

Comment: after printing the url it appears as though i didnt look at the links properly since it ends with the size of the image and not .gif or .png which comes before the size of the image. Thank you again for your help i have accepted the answer!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need first to cast the url in a string

```
@bot.command()
@commands.check(Owner)
async def avs(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    member = ctx.author if not member else member
    if str(member.avatar_url).endswith('.gif'):    # Here card the url to str
        await member.avatar_url_as(format="gif").save(fp=f"{member}.gif")
        await ctx.send(f"Saved pfp of {member}")
    else:
        await member.avatar_url_as(format="png").save(fp=f"{member}.png")
        await ctx.send(f"Saved pfp of {member}")
```